# Match multiple patterns in same line using sed

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have this string and need to extract the Name values from it (`it-IT-SMTf00, ru-RU-SMTf00, en-GB-SMTf00` etc.):

`[Voice[Name: it-IT-SMTf00, locale: ita_ITA_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: ru-RU-SMTf00, locale: rus_RUS_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: en-GB-SMTf00, locale: eng_GBR_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: pt-BR-SMTf00, locale: por_BRA_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: es-MX-SMTf00, locale: spa_MEX_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: en-US-SMTf00, locale: eng_USA_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: fr-FR-SMTf00, locale: fra_FRA_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: es-ES-SMTf00, locale: spa_ESP_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]], Voice[Name: de-DE-SMTf00, locale: deu_DEU_f00, quality: 300, latency: 300, requiresNetwork: false, features: [version=201709251, name=NA, pairedVariant=F01, gender=female]]]`

Using `regex101.com` I can match the pattern I require using this regex pattern:

`Name: ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)`

I am interested in group 1. The question is how do I do this using sed?

I have tried `echo STRING | sed -re "s/.*Name: ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).*/\1/g"` but this is greedy and only returns `de-DE-SMTf00`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/JzVkeV/2/ this pattern will capture what you want. now, i don't know exactly what do you want to do with sed.

Comment: Use `grep -oP 'Name: *\K[a-zA-Z0-9-]+' your_file`

Comment: Thanks @lucas_7_94 that works but ideally wanted to be able to run it from command line, @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks that does the trick, if you write it as an answer I'll accept `echo STRING |  grep -oP 'Name: *\K[a-zA-Z0-9-]+'` solved it for me :)